# How to deploy SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services on a network without a domain server?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ssrs

I have a small Windows network (~30 machines) and I need to deploy SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services. Because I use SQL Server Standard Edition and not Enterprise, I am forced to use Windows Authentication to the users.

I am a Linux admin, and have near zero knowledge on Active Directory. As deep as my shallow knowledge goes, I think that I would need to invest in a domain server, a mirrored backup of that domain server. I think that I need to change every computer to use this domain too, and if the domain server goes down, every computer will be unavailable.

Is there a easier way to deploy Windows Authentication **so that users can access Reporting Services from their computers** without changing the infra-structure that much?

Thanks!

Comment: I see your edit, and it does not change my answer at all. You've had 4 months to try - any success? Any failures? Relevant new information?

Comment: Whoops - so sorry. I thought your edit was recent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Windows Authentication just means that the Windows accounts on the server are what's used for SQL logins, instead of SQL-only accounts defined within SQL Server Management Studio. If the SQL server isn't in a domain (your existing case), then it will use the local Windows accounts (found with Computer Management, Users and Groups.)

You don't need to become a Windows expert to admin an MS SQL server, but you should definitely read up on the SQL Server documentation and maybe get a few hardcopy books if you're wading into this particular pool.